# Versionning changes in Preprod sandbox Salesforce Visual Studio without Scratch org

Tags: scratch-org, git, visualstudiocode

I am a Salesforce developer,
Previously, I only used the Developer Console
Now I would like to use Visual Studio.

I would do versioning without using Scratch Org, is it possible?

To do this, I would create a SFDX project related to PreProd in Visual Studio, I would normally work in Preprod, then just before deploying in Prod to retrieve my changes in a zip file in Visual Studio, unzip them in a directory and then version them. Would that sound like a good method?
Do you have another versioning method without Scratch Org?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a large topic, so I might not be able to do it justice in just a single StackOverflow answer.

The position you should try to get to is that the source control repository is the source of truth, and when you get there then specific environments become less important.

The tactical answer to your question is that Visual Studio Code with the Salesforce CLI extensions can do pulls and pushes to sandboxes. This means you can spin up your preprod sandbox, connect to it using VS Code and then just use the new source retrieve commands, and then source control the resulting files.

No need for retrieving individual zips and things :)

Comment: Thanks ! I will do this !